# VBA - highlight cells with Absolute references

Tags: vba, reference, conditional-formatting, absolute

I have inherited a massive spreadsheet with many sheets, and many formulas that have a lot of absolute references.
These sheets need to be combined into one, is there an easy way to identify absolute references quickly with VBA?
I was thinking of some conditional formatting for cells that contain "$" but that doesn't work.
Alternatively I figured a script could run through each cell and evaluate it's absolute contents, if it identifies a "$" it then formats the cell and moves on to the next.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with conditional formatting:

- Mark all your data
- Select "conditional formatting", "New rule"
- Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- Enter the formula `=FIND("$",FORMULATEXT(A1))>0` (assuming that the first cell you selected is `[A1]`. `FORMULATEXT` will look for the text of the formula of a cell and `FIND` will search for a `$` within that formula.
- Do not forget to set the formatting, e.g. a fill color

Comment: Fantastic thankyou! it works perfectly, however I have found that it doesn't work at all for cells containing conditional statements that don't evaluate to an absolute cell reference but still contain "$" however I could use the above solution to find those cells with conditional statements.

Comment: You want to conditionally format a cell that has a conditional formatting? That won't work. It would be easy to find those using VBA, but if you then format the cell with code, you will not see it because the conditional formatting will overload the cell formatting. Only idea would be to dump that cell addresses into a Sheet or a Text file.

Comment: Sorry that is incorrect, I as above, I wish to find all absolute values. The conditional formatting seems to only include those formulas with conditional *statements* that are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for even basic users:

Ctrl+F (search),
enter search parameter "$" (in this case),

Ensure the drop boxes have selected:

- Within: Sheet
- Search: By Rows
- Look in: Formulas

Uncheck the "Match entire cell contents" checkbox,
click "Find all"

In the list that appears within the search window,
select all of the entries, it will select the entire search group.

Apply formatting to the selection to highlight these cells.